# Ajax load from page that uses dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

Is it possible to dynamically load content from another page (same domain), that uses dynamic loading as well?

More specifically: There is a product feed which uses query parameters and Angularjs to specify which products will be shown and to load them.

So if I would like to load products from domain.com/products?color=red to domain.com/test

Is it somehow possible to bind the products?

Thanks

Comment: Yes of course - use ajax get method - it will load the content from another page in same domain. When you get conten from other page you will probably need to parse it in js...

Comment: That wouldn't work with dynamically loaded content?

Comment: I don't know exactly becouse i never use iframe - but maby i U use iframe you will get dynamic content with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although in order to get the javascript inside the page to run you'll have to load it into an `iframe`.

Once it's loaded into an `iframe` you can hide the `iframe` with CSS.

Comment: Did I get this right: I use iframe to load the source page into my target page and then use ajax to get content from it? How exactly would I load an element from iframe? Thanks!

Comment: @SilverRingvee yes, although you no longer have to use ajax in this context (the ajax is being done by the `iframe`'s content), instead use jQuery (or something similar) to extract the content from the `iframe`

Comment: Thanks, I figured the jQuery thing out as well. But that iframe idea was really good! Solved my problem here!